# How to get SharePoint user login name of user not a member of any site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, sharepoint-rest-api, pnp-powershell

I wanted to get the login name of all users and groups. I can only find ways to get users login names if a user is a member of some site, But I need data for each user and group which can be able to assign permission to sites.

Looking for a Solution in PowerShell or REST API.

Comment: Like, there is a new user in tenant not in any site, want to assign him permission to a site, need his login name to add him to the site via REST API , Same as for groups also

Comment: I think you need to first get all the users here: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/01/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-get-all-user-profiles.html and then run a second script that iterates all groups in all sites and cross run the result. I don't think there's a one-script-to-rule-them-all in your task.